# Not able to fire button's click in MVC 4 razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, button, click

I am new to MVC, i want to create a login control and for i have write the below code in view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginControl", "Login"))
{
    <div style="float: left; line-height: 36px;">
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">
            UserName :
        </div>
        <div style="float: right;">@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.login.UserName)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">
            Password &nbsp;&nbsp;:
        </div>
        <div style="float: right;">@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.login.UserPassword)</div>
        <br />
        <div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Login" id="Login" title="Login" />
    </div>
}
```

in controller my code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Default1/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult LoginControl(String UserName, String UserPassword)
    {
        string result = "";
        if (UserName == "ram" && UserPassword == "ram123")
        {
            result = "1";
        }
        if (result == "1")
        {
            return View("LoginControl");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password");
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am not able to get why it is working, please help me.

Comment: What is not working? I mean, do you get any errors?

Comment: @Mario no i am not getting any error. click is not firing

Comment: I think input type should be "submit" rather than "button", and in your controller add a `[HttpPost]` attribute to your action

Comment: @musefan yes it works but i am not able to get the textboxes value on controller

Comment: Parameter names must match the `name` attributes on the html elements. Check what they are, I would guess they are `login_UserName` and `login_UserPassword`. OR just use your ViewModel as your action parameter

Comment: ASP.NET MVC doesn't have "controls" and "events" like WebForms or ASP Classic. It's pure HTML and HTTP requests.

Comment: @anaximander ok i will remember it thanks for your useful help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok first of all change the input type of button to submit:

```
<input type="button" value="Login" id="Login" title="Login" />
```

Now Change the View Code as below:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginControl", "Login"))
{
    <div style="float: left; line-height: 36px;">
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">
            UserName :
        </div>
        <div style="float: right;">@Html.TextBox("UserName")
        </div>
        <br />
        <div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">
            Password &nbsp;&nbsp;:
        </div>
        <div style="float: right;">@Html.TextBox("UserPassword")
        </div>
        <br />
        <div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="Login" title="Login" />
    </div>
}
```

Hope this will help you.